# Highcharts Timeline inconsistent point width in multiple series

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm working on HighCharts Timeline chart. 
I separate data to different series because I need filter legend feature.
Here is my timeline code: [Demo (Jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/iammarcolee/4o53fkcx/)
For the data ordering, I assign 'x' attribute to each point.
But currently the width of each point is inconsistent and the point is overlap.
I expect my chart can look like [Expect Result(Jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-timeline/connector-styles) with filter feature and data ordering,
so I use integer index value to 'x' but not milliseconds.

Is that possible to be fixed? 
Thanks you very much.

**Currently using code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'timeline'
},
xAxis: {
    visible: false
},
yAxis: {
    visible: false
},
legend: {
    enabled: true
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPadding: 1,
        lineWidth: 0,
        legendType: '',
        showInLegend: true,
        colorByPoint: false,
        dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: true,
            format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' + '{point.x}:{point.name}</span>'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Series A',
    data: [{
        x: 1,
        name: 'Data A-1',
        label: 'Label A-1',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }, {
        x: 5,
        name: 'Data A-2',
        label: 'Label A-2',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }, {
        x: 8,
        name: 'Data A-3',
        label: 'Label A-3',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Series B',
    data: [{
        x: 2,
        name: 'Data B-1',
        label: 'Label B-1',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }, {
        x: 4,
        name: 'Data -2',
        label: 'Label B-2',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }, {
        x: 7,
        name: 'Data B-3',
        label: 'Label B-3',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Series C',
    data: [{
        x: 0,
        name: 'Data C-1',
        label: 'Label C-1',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }, {
        x: 3,
        name: 'Data C-2',
        label: 'Label C-2',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }, {
        x: 6,
        name: 'Data C-3',
        label: 'Label C-3',
        description: 'Some quite long description of the event.'
    }]
}]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to try another approach to achieve it because the timeline series doesn't support multiple series. My proposal is:

- create one data array with id for each point and defined color,
- add dummies series with empty data - just to display legend items for the particular points,
- use the `legendItemClick` event callback to find points assigned to the dummy series to hide/show them

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h0p57e9m/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.events.legendItemClick

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update