# Unable to visualize series correctly on custom timeline (Error, unable to access property 0, c.points is undefined)

Tags: highcharts

I am attempting to cluster a rather large amount of data segments into Series on a timeline chart. Initially, enabling the sections on the legend plotted each data point as a filterable section, but I am unable to correctly get it working with the individual series.

Here is the code being used at present:

```js
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/newestccoi/api/ccoi_visualization_engine.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            sid: <?php echo $_GET['sid'] ?>
        },
        success: function(res) {
            const time = new Highcharts.Time();
            var data = [];
            console.log(res);

            let constructedSeries = [];

            function toDateTime(secs) {
                var t = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
                t.setSeconds(secs);
                return t;
            };
            let distance = 50;
            for (value of Object.values(res)) {
                
                let seriesEntry = {};
                const arr_start = value[0];
                const arr_end = value[value.length - 1];
                

                //Construct our Data array with ALL entries in a given subsession
                for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    let tempObj = value[i];
                    let obsTime = toDateTime(tempObj.seconds);
                    temp_data = {
                        name: tempObj.notes,
                        label: tempObj.name,
                        description: arr_start.sublabel,
                        x: obsTime.getTime(),
                        
                    };
                    data.push(temp_data);
                }
                //Craft individual series entry (object) with the data object.
                console.log(distance);
                seriesEntry = {
                    dataLabels: {
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        distance: distance,
                        format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
                            '{point.x:%M:%S}</span><br/>{point.label}'
                    },

                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'circle'
                    },
                    data: data
                };

                constructedSeries.push(seriesEntry);

                //Clear data object;
                data = [];
                distance += 50;
            }
            

            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                accessibility: {
                    screenReaderSection: {
                        beforeChartFormat: '<h5>{chartTitle}</h5>' +
                            '<div>{typeDescription}</div>' +
                            '<div>{chartSubtitle}</div>' +
                            '<div>{chartLongdesc}</div>' +
                            '<div>{viewTableButton}</div>'
                    },
                    point: {
                        valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.label}. {point.description}.'
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value:%M:%S}'
                    },
                    visible: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    visible: false
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Session path timeline visualization'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'CCOI</a>'
                },
                colors: [
                    '#4185F3',
                    '#427CDD',
                    '#406AB2',
                    '#3E5A8E',
                    '#3B4A68',
                    '#363C46'
                ],
                plotOptions: {
                    timeline:{
                        legendType: '',
                        colorByPoint: false,
                        showInLegend: true,
                    }
                },
                series: constructedSeries
            });
        },

        error: function(xhr) {
            //Do something to handle our error.
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    })
```

---

Introducing the code necessary to properly display the individual Series on the legend, `legendType: ''`, broke the timeline and returned the following Javascript Error:

`Uncaught TypeError: can't access property 0, c.points is undefined`

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated! I am including a sample piece of JSON to rid any confusion on what exactly this data looks like. If believes there's a better way of doing this in Highchart, I'm open to completely redoing it as well! I have a feeling this may have to do with the fact I am using a hacky method of changing the time scale on the timeline to Minutes and Seconds, but I am not absolutely sure.

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "1",
      "notes": "Student is trying to draw star in Scratch.",
      "seconds": "0",
      "name": "start"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "1",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "30",
      "name": "independent"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "2",
      "notes": "Student asks for peer's help with problem.",
      "seconds": "30",
      "name": "start"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "2",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "30",
      "name": "interactive"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "2",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "30",
      "name": "problem_solving"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "2",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "90",
      "name": "problem_solving"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "2",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "90",
      "name": "problem_solving"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "2",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "90",
      "name": "interactive"
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "3",
      "notes": "Student opens Google Maps.",
      "seconds": "90",
      "name": "start"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": "Problem 1",
      "subsession": "3",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "135",
      "name": "independent"
    }
  ],
  "4": [
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "135",
      "name": "start"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "135",
      "name": "interactive"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "165",
      "name": "non_computing_communication"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "170",
      "name": "interactive"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "170",
      "name": "problem_solving"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "170",
      "name": "problem_solving"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "180",
      "name": "problem_solving"
    },
    {
      "sid": "1",
      "sublabel": null,
      "subsession": "4",
      "notes": null,
      "seconds": "180",
      "name": "interactive"
    }
  ]
}
```

I attempted to follow the help of this a separate stackoveflow post that goes over the method for using multiple series within a timeline, but nothing there seemed to be the cause of why I am getting this error.

## Edit

[Chart when legendType is default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXR9h.png)

[Chart when legendType is unset to ''](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaKw6.png)

My goal is to actually have the legend correctly display 1-10 like in the second image, while *actually* displaying the data. When legendType is set, for some reason or another it treats every individual data object in the `data` array as a series, when it should actually be display the 10 `series` objects that are present in the array.

If this still doesn't clear things up, let me know and I'll create a codepen!

Comment: I'm not sure what would you like to achieve. First of all, `timeline.legendType` throws errors because this option doesn't exist in Highcharts. Could you please reproduce your example in the working demo and specify your requirements?

Comment: @magdalena Thank you for the reply! I've edited my post to include an image of what is currently happening to clarify a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As I mentioned `legendType` option doesn't exist, so this needs to be removed from the code. I'm afraid that you will need to rebuild a bit your data structure because multiple series are not supported in the timeline. I would suggest following the approach outlined in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238571/highcharts-timeline-inconsistent-point-width-in-multiple-series ; Let me know in case of any inquiries!